# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_60: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to build a deep RNN where my `x_train` shape is `(318,39)` and my `y_train` has shape `(318,)`. When I execute the code below:

```py
model.add(LSTM(20,input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:]), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=20,epochs=250)
```

I'm getting following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_60: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Comment: post your full code, and shape of X_train, y_train

Comment: X_train.shape=(318,39) and y_train.shape=(318,)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `LSTM`, I am assuming your input data is sequential, i.e., you have 318 examples where each example has 39 time steps? If that is the case, you should first reshape your input data properly such as:

```
import numpy as np
X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, -1)
```

This will reshape your X_train to have a shape of `(318, 39, 1)` and then it will work (Only if my initial assumption is correct)

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

The expected input shape of the LSTM layer is `[batch, timesteps, feature]`. You're passing `[batch, timesteps]`. What you want to do is to pass `[batch, timesteps, 1]` (expand dimension on the right). You could do it like this:

```py
X_train = X_train[..., None]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just reshape the X_train

`X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],1)`

before fit function.

LSTM needs a 3D array (batch size, timesteps, features). In your case, as you have 1 feature, you need to add one extra dimension.